# Changing fullcalendar language

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

This is the first time I use Fullcalendar and i don't understand how to change the language I tryed to follow the documentation but it's not working
I used https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar
this is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.dashprof')
@section('content')
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/>




    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Emploi du temps</div>

                    <div  class="panel-body">

                         {!! $calendar->calendar() !!}    
                         {!! $calendar->script() !!}    



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            lang: 'fr'
        });

    });

</script>

@endsection
```

Comment: can you pls try to change the `{!! $calendar->calendar() !!}` to `<div id='calendar'></div>` for a moment?

Comment: @kapitan it didn't change anything

Comment: I did added the script but nothing change is this file downloaded with package ? Im using Laravel 5.8

Comment: Ok I just changed  {!! $calendar->calendar() !!}    to <div id="calendar"></div> and also I just added     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/lang-all.js"></script>
 it's changing the language but the events are not loading

Comment: then you should just manually load it using `@foreach` loop. `events: [ @foreach($events as $event) { title: {{$event->title}}, start: {{$event->from}}, end: {{$event->to}} } @endforeach ]`

Comment: any development on this?

Comment: this version of fullCalendar is very out of date and not supported. You'd be better using the new fullCalendar 4. FullCalendar is a client-side library and there is really no need to involve laravel in it. You don't need the laravel library at all to use fullCalendar.

Comment: You should use the locale option: locale: 'fr'